# Express JS writeFile then spawn Python script

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

I'm trying to setup an express router that takes a post request, write to a JSON file, and spawn a Python script to do something with the JSON file. However, the router will write the file, spawn the Python script but 'exit with child code 0' before the Python script is completed.

The router only run with either just the spawn function or with the writeFile function but not both in sequential call. I already tried breaking the function into middleware as well but still doesn't work. Not sure what is missing here...

```
sampleRouter.post('/:fileName', (req, res) => {
  let fileName = req.params.fileName;
  let data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    
  fs.writeFile(fileName, data, function (err) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    console.log("Write Success");

    const Python = spawn('python', [sample.py]);
  });

  res.send("Write Success");
});
```

Comment: What version of Node.js are you on? Are you using the async version of `fs.writeFile`?

Comment: Nodejs v14.17.5 and yes that is the async. writeFileSync is the sync version

Comment: `spawn` creates and runs the Python script asynchronously. So it won't wait until it finishes running before calling `res.send("Write Success");`. Could you include your Python script - the relevant parts (input / output)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to wait for the process to end listen to the `exit` event on the `ChildProcess`. From there call `res.send()`.

```js
sampleRouter.post('/:fileName', (req, res) => {
  let fileName = req.params.fileName;
  let data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    
  fs.writeFile(fileName, data, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }

    const python = spawn('python', [sample.py]);

    python.on('exit', (code) => {
      console.log(`python process exited with code ${code}`);
      res.send("Write Success");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I added the python.on as well but the Node doesn't wait for it to be complete, it just send a response and exit.

Comment: So does that mean that `python process exited with code ...` is never logged? Do you at least get the `Write Success` response back at the frontend? All the info you can give is welcome.

Comment: Write Success never send. It seems like the after writing the file, Node process exited with code 0. Spawn does run but it never completed.